# Case when statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following query. In this query I want to apply the where clause based on passed parameter. But the issue is that where clause is like **'value = if parameterVal = 'I' than NULL else NOT NULL'**

I've build a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER
WHERE
Column1 IS (CASE WHEN :Filter = 'I' THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END)
```

but it's not working. Help me solve this.

**UPDATE**

Updating question to elaborate question more clearly.

I've one table MASTER. Now I am passing one parameter in query that is Filter (indicated by :Filter in query).

Now when the Filter parameter's value is 'I' than it should return the following result.

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER WHERE Column1 IS NULL
```

but if the passed argument is not equal to 'I' than,

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER
WHERE  (Filter = 'I'  AND Column1 IS NULL)
     OR 
       (Filter <> 'I' AND Column1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This didn't returned the result as expected. For more clarification I've updated question.

Comment: Have a look now I have updated the answer. you should have grasped the main idea from the previous solution, it really isn't this hard :)

Comment: I should have but I didn't got it :). Thanks a lot for the answer and your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on using a CASE the `SELECT` could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MASTER
  WHERE CASE
          WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND FILTER = 'I' THEN 1
          WHEN COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL AND FILTER <> 'I' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END = 1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/685b0/1)

Frankly, though, I think that this is very difficult to interpret, and I suggest that @MAli's version is better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This didn't returned the result as expected. For more clarification I've updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though it's working I went for the M.Ali's answer. Thank a lot for your time.

Answer (score -3):

Your case has assignment not equality check

Comment: There is no "assignment" in the statement.